# How to set Switch value to on/off and prevent toggled method call in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

In PCL project, with Xamarin forms, I am setting Switch position to on/off, This calls Toggled event. In switch toggled event there is confirmation alert, if user selects "NO" it will again set switch to previous state.
The problem is, toggled method being called again and again if I press no. I want to prevent the method call.

```
Switch switcher = new Switch
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};
switcher.Toggled += switcher_Toggled;

void switcher_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {

            bool alert;

            if (this._isConnectionStatusOpen == true)
            {
                alert = await DisplayAlert("Close ", "Are you sure you want to close connection?", "Yes", "No");
            }
            else
            {
                alert = await DisplayAlert("Open", "Are you sure you want to Open connection?", "Yes", "No");

            }

            if (alert != true)
            {
                Switch thisSender = (Switch)sender;
                thisSender.IsToggled = !thisSender.IsToggled;
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there any simple way to implement it?

Comment: Are you using an MVVM framework?

Comment: No, I am not using MVVM. Its PCL project with Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Why don't you just set the `On` property?

Comment: Switch class doesn't shows 'On' property.

Comment: Whoops, seems they renamed it or I'm just confused.. It's the 'IsToggled' property, see [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Switch/)

Comment: IsToggled should work, Let me try.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis IsToggled Works, however it also calls the 
Toggled" event. Which goes in to infinite loop. I am setting IsToggled true/false again after user's confirmation.

Comment: Update your question with some sample code please

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Added code and updated description

Comment: Set a bool for isAlert shown and do not show again if switch is false and the bool is true.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a NoLoop bool.

```
private bool NoLoop { get; set; }

void switcher_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                if (NoLoop)
                {
                    NoLoop = false;
                    return;
                }
                bool alert;

                if (this._isConnectionStatusOpen == true)
                {
                    alert = await DisplayAlert("Close ", "Are you sure you want to close connection?", "Yes", "No");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert = await DisplayAlert("Open", "Are you sure you want to Open connection?", "Yes", "No");

                }

                if (alert != true)
                {
                    NoLoop = true;
                    Switch thisSender = (Switch)sender;
                    thisSender.IsToggled = !thisSender.IsToggled;

                }
            });
        }
```